# How to generate a Maven.pom file (not pom.xml)?

Tags: maven, java

This seems not so easy to google because results about the normal ***pom.xml*** are overwhelming.

So, I just have learned there are also Maven artefact related files with .pom extension. This seems to be some special thing about how repositories work - a meta-file for an artefact?

For example, if you check folder contents for an artefact in your local repository, you will find these files in any artefact folder I guess, just like in the path below.

```
\.m2\repository\org\json\json\20090211\json-20090211.pom
```

Contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <!-- this POM is released under an Apache 2.0 license-->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20090211</version>
  <name>JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)</name>
  <description>
    JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format.
    It is easy for humans to read and write. It is easy for machines to parse and generate.
    It is based on a subset of the JavaScript Programming Language, Standard ECMA-262 3rd Edition
    - December 1999. JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses
    conventions that are familiar to programmers of the C-family of languages, including C, C++, C#,
    Java, JavaScript, Perl, Python, and many others.
    These properties make JSON an ideal data-interchange language.
  </description>
  <url>http://www.json.org/java/index.html</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>provided without support or warranty</name>
      <url>http://www.json.org/license.html</url>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <organization>
    <name>JSON</name>
    <url>http://json.org/</url>
  </organization>

  <dependencies/>
</project>
```

**Question:** What is exactly this file and is it possible to generate this file as part of a Maven build? Or do we have to create these files manually as part of the codebase ?

(In the context of what I am doing, I use generic Artifactory deployment plugin for Bamboo to deploy artefacts there but this ***.pom*** file is not being created automatically).

UPD I have solved my problem by using a copy of the pom.xml as this pom file and it works but I consider this can not be the correct way.

Comment: You may be interested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629621/what-are-pom-files-in-maven-build-artifacts), tip for google search, surround `.pom` with quotes, the question above is the first link for the search `maven and ".pom" files`

Comment: thx - I followed the quoted link and finally found the anwer in one another comment:
"yes the pom needs to be there and yes I can be just a copy of an included pom. Local repositories like artifactory actually just extract an included pom if you upload a jar." now what I do with this thread? self-answer..?

Comment: yes self answering sounds a good option

Comment: Could you post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795427/why-maven-is-looking-for-pom-file-when-jar-is-present-in-the-repository/7795499#7795499):

> Every jar needs to have a pom file describing it, you can just add
>   something simple like this:

Every jar needs to have a pom file describing it, you can just add something simple like this:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    aGroup
    aArtifactId
    aVersion
    jar
    a Name